# Plotting multiple function curves in ggplot using a loop or lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following data:

```
coef <- list(c(47, 2, 0, 0), 
             c(7, 42, -8, 0),
             c(78, -71, 43, -7))

my_data <- data.frame("x" = rep(1:4, times = 20))

cols <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

I would like to plot a function for each vector of coefficients in the object `coef`.

However, using a for loop does not work.

```
library(ggplot2)    
g1 <- ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = x)) 

    for(i in 1:3){
    my_fun <- function(x){
        sum(as.vector(outer(x, 0:3, FUN="^")) * coef[[i]])
    }
    my_fun <- Vectorize(my_fun)
    g1 <- (g1 + stat_function(fun = my_fun, aes(col = cols[i]), lwd = 1.2))

    print(g1)
}
```

The result is supposed to look (somehow) like this:
[image]

Is there a way to use lapply instead of the loop? Or can I modify the for-loop to fix this problem?

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but one issue is that your function is called `poly_fun`, but you call `my_function` in the loop. Also, your function needs a value for `k`, but `k` is not an argument to the function. You should also take the function declaration outside of the loop. It only needs to be declared once, not each time through the loop.

Comment: Pretty close, though the cubic one ends a bit low, for some reason: `library(tidyverse); data.frame(x = seq(1, 4, length.out = 100), tcrossprod(outer(seq(1, 4, length.out = 100), 0:3, \`^\`), do.call(rbind, coef))) %>% gather(var, y, -x) %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, color = var)) + geom_path()`

Comment: @alistaire That is a workaround I could use, but I would rather like to solve the problem with a combination of lapply() and stat_function() if there is a way to do so

Comment: @eipi10 Sorry I overlooked that one when I simplified the code for stackoverflow. I fixed it so you can run the code. The function declaration can not be taken out of the loof because in each cycle, the i-th vector of coefficients is selected in the function. And that is the main problem I have. I would like to plot the same function multiple times, but with different coefficients

Comment: Looping doesn't work well with ggplot unless you're making lots of plots (which itself is usually ill-advised). It's much simpler to put your data in long form, which lets you do a lot more useful things in ggplot. All that said, you _could_ run `stat_function` once for each set of coefficients: `Reduce(function(g, betas){
    g + stat_function(fun = function(x){outer(x, 0:3, \`^\`) %*% betas})
}, coef, init = ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:4), aes(x = x)))`, though there's no way to get a legend without hacks.